# Treebeard - No module found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, adminlte

I installed Treebeard using

```
pip install django-adminlte-ui
```

Installation is successful.

But still it shows:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.treebeard'

This is my installed app:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.treebeard',
    'crud.apps.CrudConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_select2',
    'django_ajax',
    'treebeard',
]
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: did you add it in INSTALLED_APPD in settings.py

Comment: Did you install it in the virtual environment that you are working with? If you are not working with a virtual environment, start working with one.

Comment: I have same error. virtual: yes, django-treebeard: yes... plz advise

Answer (score 0):

use pip3 instead pip:

`pip3 install django-adminlte-ui`

for installing pip3 on ubuntu you can use:

`apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Installation is done,
It still shows the same error.

Comment: did you install treebeard?

`pip3 install django-treebeard`

https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

@imshreehari

Comment: Yes i installed.

Answer (score 0):

write treebeard only instead of django.contrib.treebeard

Solution :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'crud.apps.CrudConfig',
'crispy_forms',
'django_select2',
'django_ajax',
'treebeard',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) and [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'treebearddjango_otp'

Because I put `'treebeard'` of `django-treebeard` before the apps of `django-two-factor-auth` in [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'treebeard', # django-treebeard's
    'django_otp',                    # django-two-factor-auth's
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static', # django-two-factor-auth's
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',   # django-two-factor-auth's
    'two_factor'                     # django-two-factor-auth's
]
```

So, I put `'treebeard'` of `django-treebeard` after the apps of `django-two-factor-auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_otp',                    # django-two-factor-auth's
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static', # django-two-factor-auth's
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',   # django-two-factor-auth's
    'two_factor'                     # django-two-factor-auth's
    'treebeard', # django-treebeard's
]
```